# Why Won't Minecraft Let Me Play Offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

My computer has no internet access. Every time I log in the launcher says can't connect to minecraft.net, but I'm playing offline- not online. I tried restoring my computer because I'm already logged in but it wants me to do is log in.

Logging in doesn't work because, as I said, I'm not connected to the internet. Why can't I just play offline?
 I was online 8 months ago.

Comment: Have you ever played Minecraft online on that computer? How long ago was it?

Answer (score 3):

While you can play Minecraft offline, you still need to have logged in on a Minecraft account. This is used to verify that you actually own the game. If you are not logged in and don't have an internet connection, you won't be able to log in.

You can install Minecraft from a USB drive but you will need internet access, at least temporarily, to log in once. Once you've done that, you'll be able to play offline.

Comment: it should also be noted that even if you log in, a profile needs you to have download the files for the version it's playing. Once you have donwloaded these you can then copy the launcher and the .minecraft folder to a different computer and play offline. my main computer doesn't connect to the internet at all but it's the one i play minecraft on. updates and Forge installation i do on a laptop that's connected but not powerful enough to play minecraft

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can play offline, you still need to be logged in. You only need to log in once, and then you are done. I recommend you to connect through an Ethernet cable and then log in.